# URLSession crashing app with no log

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to make a POST request to a php script with some JSON data using Swift. When I run the following code my app crashes and there is no information logged to the console.

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {
     let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.centrohq.com/api/payment/")!
     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
     request.httpMethod = "POST"
     request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     request.httpBody = jsonData

     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
           print(response)
     })
     task.resume()
}
```

Comment: To better diagnose the problem you can register a global exception handler with `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`... this will give you the exception and the stacktrace, and might help in finding out what's wrong.

Comment: Don't *prettyPrint*  server request data. The server doesn't care at all. And don't use `NSURL` and `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3+. Use the native structs.

Comment: can you give an example of how to implement NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try unwrapping the url. I've had a few issues in the past by simply not safely unwrapping the url passed in:

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.centrohq.com/api/payment/") {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            print(response)
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a completely valid URL, so that can't be the cause of the issue. You can determine if a URL can be forced unwrapped safely or not just by looking at it. Moreover, you shouldn't be using `NSURL` and `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

This code was not the cause of the error. Another piece of code executed at the same time that caused it to fail.